# Hiding elements with date loop jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to hide elements (div's) but with date loop.

I have this table structure:

**HTML**

---

```
<div class="container-a">
<div class="container-b">
<div class="container-c">
<table border="1"style="width:98%">
   <tr>
      <td width="220" height="100">
         1
      </td>
      <td width="200">
         2
      </td>
      <td width="300">
         <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
            <span>25/01/2016 13:30</span>
            <div>
      </td>
      <td width="120">
      4
      </td>
      <td width="120">
      5
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="side-color">
</div>
<div class="tam">
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-b">
<div class="container-c">
<table border="1"style="width:98%">
   <tr>
      <td width="220" height="100">
         1
      </td>
      <td width="200">
         2
      </td>
      <td width="300">
         <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
            <span>24/01/2016 13:30</span>
            <div>
      </td>
      <td width="120">
      4
      </td>
      <td width="120">
      5
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="side-color">
</div>
<div class="tam">
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-b">
<div class="container-c">
<table border="1"style="width:98%">
   <tr>
      <td width="220" height="100">
         1
      </td>
      <td width="200">
         2
      </td>
      <td width="300">
         <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
            <span>23/10/2015 13:30</span>
            <div>
      </td>
      <td width="120">
      4
      </td>
      <td width="120">
      5
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="side-color">
</div>
<div class="tam">
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-b">
<div class="container-c">
<table border="1"style="width:98%">
   <tr>
      <td width="220" height="100">
         1
      </td>
      <td width="200">
         2
      </td>
      <td width="300">
         <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
            <span>18/11/2015 13:30</span>
            <div>
      </td>
      <td width="120">
      4
      </td>
      <td width="120">
      5
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="side-color">
</div>
<div class="tam">
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-b">
<div class="container-c">
<table border="1"style="width:98%">
   <tr>
      <td width="220" height="100">
         1
      </td>
      <td width="200">
         2
      </td>
      <td width="300">
         <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
            <span>18/08/2015 13:30</span>
            <div>
      </td>
      <td width="120">
      4
      </td>
      <td width="120">
      5
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="side-color">
</div>
<div class="tam">
</div>
</div>
<div class="container-b">
<div class="container-c">
<table border="1"style="width:98%">
   <tr>
      <td width="220" height="100">
         1
      </td>
      <td width="200">
         2
      </td>
      <td width="300">
         <div id="step_form_1" class="order-steps">
            <span>18/01/2015 13:30</span>
            <div>
      </td>
      <td width="120">
      4
      </td>
      <td width="120">
      5
      </td>
   </tr>
</table>
</div>
<div class="side-color">
</div>
<div class="tam">
</div>
</div>
```

I have this `for loop`  to obtain the last 6 months.

**Jquery**

---

```
var str="";
 var monthNames = [ "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12" ];

                        for ( var i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {

                      var now = new Date();
                      var date = new Date(now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - i));
                      var datex = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

                            str += ""+ monthNames[date.getMonth()] + "/" + date.getFullYear()+"\n";

                    }
                    alert(str);
```

And I have this code to find every element inside Div and hide/show

```
$(".container-c table tr td div#step_form_1").each(function()
                  {

                        $(this).find('span').filter(":contains('"+str+"')").length > 0 ? $(this).show() : $(this).parents('div.container-c').fadeOut();
                  });
```

But the way I put the variable inside `filter(":contains('"+str+"')")` hides all and not the array.

Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6x80vabm/23/)

Answer (score 0):

You are actually doing a `string concatenation` instead of adding the elements into the `array`. You need to declare the `str` variable as an array and add the elements into it using `push`. During your each loop, you can use `index` of the `each` function to iterate through the corresponding element in the array.

```
 var pol = "25/01/2016";
 var str= [];
 var monthNames = [ "01", "02", "03", "04", "05", "06", "07", "08", "09", "10", "11", "12" ];

                        for ( var i = 5; i >= 0; i--) {

                      var now = new Date();
                      var date = new Date(now.setMonth(now.getMonth() - i));
                      var datex = ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2) + "-" + ("0" + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + "-" + date.getFullYear();

                            str.push(monthNames[date.getMonth()] + "/" + date.getFullYear());

                    }
                    alert(str);
                     $(".container-c table tr td div#step_form_1 span").each(function(index)
                  {

                        $(this).filter(":contains('"+str[index]+"')").length > 0 ? $(this).show() : $(this).parents('div.container-c').fadeOut();
                  });
```

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6x80vabm/24/

Comment: thanks for you support, but i have a question, why only show 2 elements? if the `loop` contains since 01/2016 until 08/2015 and i have in the table content with 01/2016,11/2015,10/2015,08/2015 and my last date is 01/15 that the element hide is the last.